Is there a shortcut to go down a slide while focused on speaker notes?
One of my professors uploads their PowerPoint slide decks for students to reference. I have been using the Speaker Notes section of each slide to add notes or details while watching lecture. The thing that's annoying me is, when my cursor is focused on the Speaker Notes, pressing Down or Right or PgDn will navigate the text cursor, and not avance to the next slide, so I have to click on some other part of the screen in order to use those shortcuts.
So I'm wondering if there is some sequence of key presses, if not a dedicated shortcut, that allows me to advance to the next slide while focused on the Speaker Notes without having to use my mouse. I also am looking for a way to refocus the Speaker Notes after avancing to the next slide.

Instead of viewing the presentation in normal view, choose View | Notes Pages.
You'll get an image of the slide plus a much larger view of your own notes text.
And PageDown will take you to the next slide's Notes page.

Oh I didn't realize that the notes on that page is actually the speaker notes. Two more questions: 1) is there a better way to focus on the notes other than pressing tab? 2) is there a way to show the left hand slide bar while in this mode?

By "focus on the notes", I assume you mean to put the text cursor in the notes text so you can write there. Tab would be about it, but deleting any extraneous footer/header/number/date placeholders from the master should save a bit of extra tabbing. But no, can't show the slide thumbnails in this view.

Your core issue is that you are using the Notes section for a purposes it was not intended. Notes in Powerpoint are Speakers Notes, not student notes.
In its default state, PowerPoint requires focus for any of its default slideshow key commands to function.
The options I can think of:

A separate utility, such as Auto Hotkey to write some script that TAKES focus back to the show, advances the slide, and RETURNS focus to the notes section so you can continue taking notes.
Create a copy of the show, use the PointPoint viewer to run the slideshow and take notes in the other copy open in the main PowerPoint program.
The better option overall, use a different tool for taking notes, such as OneNote.

Really, the best option is the 3rd option. There are applications that are intended for taking and storing and organizing and presenting notes, and there are applications for presenting slides. There are differences between these, and as you build up custom processes or code to try to stretch one into the other's shape, you introduce complexity, which is more places for processes to fail, accidents to happen, errors to crop up, etc.

I intend these notes more like personal footnotes, so my main priority is that these notes and the slides are in the same place, while quality/depth/structure/formatting/... are not important.
